# Vuetify Calander

Tags: vue.js, vuetify.js

Im using vue calender with vuetify version 2.1.x .

I want to get time from a specific slot when we click on it so i do this like : @click:time="test"

```html
<v-calendar
  ref="calendar"
  :locale="$i18n.locale"
  v-model="schedulerObj.calViewValue"
  :weekdays="weekday"
  :type="type"
  :events="events"
  :event-overlap-mode="mode"
  :event-overlap-threshold="30"
  :event-color="getEventColor"
  :interval-minutes="schedulerObj.intervalDuration"
  @click:time="test"
>
</v-calendar>
```

But when my "test" function is called it gives event/object which dont have hours in it. And its only in vuetify 2.1.x and not in previous version.

Comment: Why don't you get the value of your `v-model` ?

Comment: Did your problem solved? @Naqsh Ali

Answer (score 0):

You have to destruct whatever you need from the object that it returns. [Here](https://vuetifyjs.com/en/api/v-calendar/#events-click:time) is the instruction. As the instruction in **vuetify** doc says :

> The click event at a specific time in the day view. The event passed is the day & time object.

This is the whole object:

```js
{
  date: string,
  time: string,
  year: number,
  month: number,
  day: number,
  hour: number,
  minute: number,
  weekday: number,
  hasDay: boolean,
  hasTime: boolean,
  past: boolean,
  present: boolean,
  future: boolean,
  timeToY: (time: string | number | {hour: number, minute: number}, clamp: boolean = false): number | false,
  timeDelta: (time: string | number | {hour: number, minute: number}): number | false,
  minutesToPixels: (minutes: number): number,
  week: [
    {
      date: string,
      time: string,
      year: number,
      month: number,
      day: number,
      hour: number,
      minute: number,
      weekday: number,
      hasDay: boolean,
      hasTime: boolean,
      past: boolean,
      present: boolean,
      future: boolean
    }
  ]
}
```